# Matching excel array in a specific logic requirement

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, array-formulas

I wanted to create a formula that will identify the first "non N.A."(that is to say number) starting from the right for an array, and then return the row number for that first "non N.A." that was spotted in the array:

```
1        2       3       4       5
1.625   1.625   N.A.    N.A.    N.A.
```

I tried using this formula:

```
   {=MATCH(FALSE,C4:G4="N.A.")}
```

In this circumstance, it returns a row 2.

But if the array is in this form:

```
1        2       3        4      5
N.A.    1.625   N.A.    N.A.    N.A.
```

The formula will return an error.

Again if the array is in this form:

```
1       2          3      4     5
N.A.    N.A.    1.625   1.625   N.A.
```

The formula returns row 4 which is correct.

Therefore, I need help on this formula. Thank you very much. Any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cells contains either number either `N.A.`, try this one:

```
=MATCH(9.9E+307,C4:G4)
```

otherwise this array formula:

```
=MATCH(1,1/(C4:G4<>"N.A."))
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it

Comment: Magic! Can you explain what is going on here?

Comment: Sure:) we omit third parametr of `Match`, excel expect ordered array and would tries to find aprox match. Since `9.9E+307` is almost the biggest number in excel, formula always would return last number in array (excel expected sorted array and thinks that lats number is the biggest and closest to `9.9E+307`). A little bit messy:)

Comment: Hi Simoco, this formula works very well in my requirement. Thanks a lot for your formula and the explanation. =)